# The force in Coulomb's Law of Electrostatic Forces seems really high

Tags: capacitor

I am reading Radio Shack's *Basic Electronics*, and it presents Coulomb's law of electrostatic forces:

$$F=k \frac{Q_1Q_2}{S^2}$$

and they say k is \$9\text{x}10^9\text{ newton meter}^2/\text{coulomb}^2\$ in a vacuum. I have checked elsewhere and this is consistent. But it seems way too high.

Let's say I have two small objects with one coulomb of charge each, separated by a distance of one meter. Then we have  a force of attraction or repulsion of \$9\text{x}10^9\$ newtons. If one newton is equivalent to 9.8 kg on Earth, then the force would be over 88 billion kilograms.

So then I thought perhaps the coulomb is a very large quantity. But no, a one farad capacitor can hold one coulomb (at a drop of one volt, which I don't understand just yet). I do know that one farad is a rather large capacitor, but not that large. I can still hold one in my hand.

Comment: That 1-farad capacitor is not human-scale (plate separation is sub-microscopic). To get a feel for human-scale distances, consider the Van de Graaff. Voltages are some fraction of a megavolt, capacitance is 10's of picofarads, and distance about a meter. You can feel the force directly, and notice the strain of transporting charge up its belt once voltage climbs high enough.

Comment: It is like grams and kilograms. Grams are good for laboratory measurements, but too small for industrial or commercial use (of most goods). So kilogram was accepted as the SI unit. Similarly, coulomb happened to be defined too large while in most circuits we deal with nano coulombs or micro coulombs.

Comment: _"If one newton is equivalent to 9.8 kg on Earth,"_ - but is it?

Comment: You can't use Coulomb's law because the plates aren't point charges. Instead, the force can be computed by taking the energy stored and divide it by the effective plate separation, whatever that is. You know that the energy is \$\frac12 C V^2\$. What you don't know is the effective plate separation. In any case, you just divide the potential energy stored by the plate separation to get the force.

Answer (score 4):

Your exact calculation is done as an example over on [Physics Classroom](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/Class/estatics/U8L3b.cfm#:%7E:text=Coulomb%27s%20law%20states%20that%20the,distance%20between%20the%20two%20objects.). They say:

> The force of repulsion of two +1.00 Coulomb charges held 1.00 meter apart is 9 billion Newton. This is an incredibly large force that compares in magnitude to the weight of more than 2000 jetliners.

> This problem was chosen primarily for its conceptual message. Objects simply do not acquire charges on the order of 1.00 Coulomb. In fact, more likely Q values are on the order of 10-9 or possibly 10-6 Coulombs. For this reason, a Greek prefix is often used in front of the Coulomb as a unit of charge. Charge is often expressed in units of microCoulomb (µC) and nanoCoulomb (nC).

I've never done these calculations and don't have a good mental picture of what 1 C charges would "look like" so I'll be interested to see some other answers on the subject.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. The book gives an example with -50C and 25C. I'm sure it is done to make the math easy. On the web I found a similar example. But this still doesn't explain one thing, that a one farad capacitor can hold one coulomb at a drop of one volt.

Comment: Where this breaks down is that you can easily have a capacitor charged with 1 coulomb of charge, all it takes is to feed 1A into 1F capacitor for 1 second and the capacitor charges to 1V and holds 1 coulomb of charge. But the charges are separated by plates of some area A and there is a molecular layer of insulation between the plates so distance h is in the nanometers (1E-9). In contrast, if you want to take an object, and remove 1 coulomb worth of electrons from it to a distance of 1 meter, then yes, the energy needed to do that and the resulting force are both huge.

Comment: @Justme: that looks like an answer.

Comment: @Justme But a very small number for the distance greatly increases the force.

Comment: I think the main point is that charges stored in capacitors are not point charges. For example this link addresses the logic behind the issue: [link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elefor.html#c2)

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense.

Comment: @Ishq, thanks for accepting my answer but I think you should unaccept for a couple of days to encourage other answers. You'll get much better than mine and probably some additional practical considerations. Then accept the best - which is unlikely to be this one.

Answer (score 4):

> So then I thought perhaps the coulomb is a very large quantity. But
> no, a one farad capacitor can hold one coulomb (at a drop of one volt,
> which I don't understand just yet). I do know that one farad is a
> rather large capacitor, but not that large. **I can still hold one in my**
> **hand**.

That 1 F capacitor probably has a voltage rating of 5 V or less, and the effective plate separation is less than a nanometer. Now consider a single layer air capacitor with plate separation of 1 m. What plate area would be required to get 1 F?

The formula for capacitance is C = εA/d, where ε is the permittivity of the dielectric, A is the area, and d is the spacing. The permittivity of air is ~8.85x10<sup>-12</sup>. With such a low value the plate area must be enormous; ~113 billion square meters for 1 F. That equates to a plate size of 336 km x 336 km. If the plates were made of 1 mm thick aluminuim they would weigh ~300 billion kilograms each.

That's a bit oversized for storing one coulomb at 1 V, but how much charge *could* it store? Practical spacing of air capacitors is ~6 mm for a 10 kV rating. Extrapolating to 1 m  we get ~1.7 MV, which would store 1.7 million coulombs and 1.4 terajoules = ~390 MWh of electrical energy.